# Rendering JSON for multiple Rails objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

This might be a terribly simple question, but this is just something I noticed that is bothering me.

I'm trying to render JSON from one of my controller's methods, but it's giving me a "undefined method `new' for nil:NilClass" error.

Here's the code that's causing the problem:

```
def index
    @users = User.all
    render json: @users
end
```

I noticed that when I try to render only one object to JSON, everything works fine:

```
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    render json: @user
end
```

Or when I call `to_json` on the @users object:

```
def index
    @users = User.all
    render json: @users.to_json
end
```

I was under the impression that calling `render json:` was implicitly calling `to_json` anyway, so why would calling that twice solve my issue?

Comment: I suppose this is because the response has to be the only one json object, not many :)

Comment: Your code looks reasonable. Can you post the rest of the `undefined method new` stack trace?

Comment: @rubchick that's what I was thinking, but I was just a little confused as to why `render json:` wouldn't automatically take the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that it's an issue with `@users` being an array of objects that needs each object to be converted first before the whole array is reassembled and output as JSON.